# Getting mocha error in command prompt

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

when I run a sample js file in CMD . it showing error like Error: Cannot find test framework "mocha". Please help me to resolve this one.

**Error after running tests:**

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')") 
       ^^^^^^^  
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16) 
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:343:32) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) 
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10) 
at startup (node.js:139:18) 
at node.js:968:3
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "macaca-test-sample",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "macaca-test-sample",
    "keywords": [
        "sample"
    ],
    "main": "index.js",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git://github.com/xudafeng/macaca-test-sample.git"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "mocha": "^3.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "jshint": "*",
        "mocha": "^3.2.0",
        "pre-commit": "1.1.1",
        "webdriver-client": "~1.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha",
        "jshint": "make jshint"
    },
    "pre-commit": [
        "jshint"
    ],
    "homepage": "github.com/xudafeng/macaca-test-sample";,
    "author": "xudafeng",
    "email": "xudafeng@126.com",
    "blog": "xdf.me";,
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: share code please.

Comment: install mocha `globally`

Comment: Shaharyar , how can I do that

Comment: `npm install --global mocha`

Comment: HI Shaharyar , thanks for the help it works. But running it again it showing another issue like this "basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3"

Comment: Which nodejs framework are you using?

Comment: Its a new framework called macaca

Comment: Can you share your project's `package.json` file?

Comment: {
  "name": "macaca-test-sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "macaca-test-sample",
  "keywords": [
    "sample"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/xudafeng/macaca-test-sample.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mocha": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "*",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "pre-commit": "1.1.1",
    "webdriver-client": "~1.0.0"
  },

Comment: "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "jshint": "make jshint"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "jshint"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/xudafeng/macaca-test-sample",
  "author": "xudafeng",
  "email": "xudafeng@126.com",
  "blog": "http://xdf.me",
  "license": "MIT"
}

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of [istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul) on windows and you have this npm as dependency in [macacajs](https://github.com/macacajs/macaca-cli/blob/master/package.json#L39):

Explained [here](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul#usage-on-windows) as:

> Istanbul assumes that the command passed to it is a JS file (e.g.
>   Jasmine, vows etc.), this is however not true on Windows where npm
>   wrap bin files in a .cmd file. Since Istanbul can not parse .cmd files
>   you need to reference the bin file manually.
>
> Here is an example using Jasmine 2:
>
> ```
> istanbul cover node_modules\jasmine\bin\jasmine.js
> ```
>
> In order to use this cross platform (e.i. Linux, Mac and Windows), you can insert the above line into the script object in your
>   package.json file but with normal slash.
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "test": "istanbul cover node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js"
> }
> ```

So the simple solution is to add the above snippet into your package.json.

Answer (score -1):

Editing the `package.json` or `/node_modules/.bin/mocha` files, but did not work.

The only solution, so far for me, was to install mocha globally:

```
npm install -g mocha
```